# JavaScript Scoping - Passing callback to already defined function

Tags: javascript, callback, scoping

The title is a bit weird, don't quite know the best way to explain it in a sentence...

At present there is an object with 3 functions; func, funcSuccess, and funcFailure. func contains a jQuery ajax request, with this.funcSuccess as the success callback, and funcError as the error callback. func is passed a callback for any success values to be passed back to, however this callback needs to be executed in the funcSuccess code.

Here's the code:

```
var Obj =

  { func: function (callback) {
      $.ajax(
        { type: 'POST'
        , url: '/func'
        , success: this.funcSuccess
        , error: this.funcError
        }
      )
    }

  , funcSuccess: function (res) {
      // THIS IS WHERE CALLBACK IS NEEDED
      callback(res.thing)
    }

  , funcError: function (res) {
      debug(res)
    }

  }
```

I'm wondering if there's a tidier way to do it rather than having:

```
var that = this
$.ajax(
  { type: 'POST'
  , url: '/func'
  , success: function (res) {
      that.funcSuccess(res)
    }
  , error: this.funcError
  }
)
```

Pretty sure I'm missing something obvious, just not quite with it today...

Comment: That won't help much, `callback` is still `undefined` in the `funcSuccess` - you would need to pass it explicitly in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about storing the callback explicitly in your object, so you don't have to worry about closure scopes:

```
var Obj =

  { func: function (callback) {
      //this.callback = callback;
      $.ajax(
        { type: 'POST'
        , url: '/func'
        , success: $.proxy(this.funcSuccess, this, callback)
        , error: $.proxy(this.funcError, this)
        }
      )
    }

  , funcSuccess: function (callback, res) {
      callback(res.thing)
    }

  , funcError: function (res) {
      debug(res)
    }

  }
```

Edit: I forgot to bind the callbacks to `this`. In JQuery you can do it with `$.proxy`, see changes above.

Edit: A further tidy (jQuery 1.6 allows for this) with passing the callback as an argument to `$.proxy`, so no need to attach it to the current object.

Comment: To expand on it not working, `this` within the funcSuccess function at that point is the $.ajax function.

Just saw edit, ignore!

Comment: Added another edit with the final solution I used. Thanks @fab =D

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `callback` into the `funcSucess`, else it won't have access to it. Here by using a closure:

```
var Obj = {
    func: function (callback) {
        return $.ajax({
            type: 'POST', 
            url: '/func',
            success: this.makeFuncSuccess(callback),
            error: this.funcError
        });
    }, makeFuncSuccess(callback) {
        return function funcSuccess (res) {
            callback(res.thing);
        };
    },
    funcError: function (res) {
       debug(res)
    }
};
```